# Como mudar a cor do ícone dentro de um Rectangle - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps

Preciso alterar a cor do ícone do meu button para "Cor Branca", mas não sei como fazê-lo. Estou usando um Pack de ícones do Mahapss... Já ví fazer isso na net usando o ContentControl do GRID, mas estando dentro de um rectangle, eu não faço ideia... Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<Button Width="148" Height="48" Margin="0 0 10 0" Style="{StaticResource susButton}">
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">


            <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0 0 7 0">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}" Stretch="None" />
                </Rectangle.Fill>

            </Rectangle>

            <TextBlock Text="Novo Cadastro">

            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a referência da biblioteca, essa seria a solução:

```
<Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0 0 7 0" Fill="White">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}" Stretch="Fill" />
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

[Fonte](http://mahapps.com/guides/icons-and-resources.html)

Comment: Obrigado Leandro Angelo. Funcionou direitinho! :)